# Editing with a Dynamically generated table rows with html input controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I am using the below code to dynamically generate controls and insert their value in the database and it is working perfectly well. The problem is that I also want to sue the same view to return and update records.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Attribute_Count; ++i)
{
    <tbody id="attribute-row">
        <tr>
            <td class="left">

                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AttributeName[i])
                <div class="validation-area">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.AttributeName[i])
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Attribute_SortOrder[i])</td>
            <td class="left"><a onclick="$('#attribute-row' + i).remove();" class="button">-</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
```

Jquery:

```
var attribute_row = 1;

function addattribute() {
    html = '<tbody id="attribute-row' + attribute_row + '">';
    html += '  <tr>';
    html += '    <td class="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.AttributeName)<div class="validation-area">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.AttributeName)</div></td>';
    html += '    <td class="right"><input type="text" name="Attribute_SortOrder" id="Attribute_SortOrder"></td>';
    html += '    <td class="left"><a onclick="$(\'#attribute-row' + attribute_row + '\').remove();" class="button">-</a></td>';
    html += '  </tr>';
    html += '</tbody>';
    $('#attribute tfoot').before(html);
    attribute_row++;
    $('#Attribute_Count').val(attribute_row);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The code I pasted is for insert. I want to return the data with an IList for edit.